# Extract both CSS and HTML comments from HTML doc (Python)

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am passing HMTL code into BeautifulSoup using Python, and my output is erred by HTML commenting. I have this python script to remove HTML comments, but it fails to remove HTML comments nested with CSS comments.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment   

   input_text = ""

   for line in open('output.txt'):
           input_text+=line

  soup = BeautifulSoup(input_text)
  comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
  [comment.extract() for comment in comments]
  print soup
```

For example, it removes all HTML comments from my test input except for:

```
<!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:Calibri; panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:Verdana; panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:inherit;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal {margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; font-size:12.0pt; font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink {mso-style-priority:99; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {mso-style-priority:99; color:purple; text-decoration:underline;} span.EmailStyle17 {mso-style-type:personal-reply; font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif; color:#1F497D;} .MsoChpDefault {mso-style-type:export-only; font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} @page WordSection1 {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;} div.WordSection1 {page:WordSection1;} -->
```

Here is a chunk of code from the input that includes 2 comments that are successfully removed after running my script on it, as well as the comment that is not removed:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"> <!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);} </style><![endif]--><style><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:Calibri; panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:Verdana; panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:inherit;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal {margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; font-size:12.0pt; font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink {mso-style-priority:99; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {mso-style-priority:99; color:purple; text-decoration:underline;} span.EmailStyle17 {mso-style-type:personal-reply; font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif; color:#1F497D;} .MsoChpDefault {mso-style-type:export-only; font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} @page WordSection1 {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;} div.WordSection1 {page:WordSection1;} --></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" /> </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit"> <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" /> </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
```

I'm not sure of the best way of going about removing the CSS comments first. I shouldn't need to bother removing the content of the CSS comments, just the /* */, as the rest should be stripped with the HTML comment it is nested within

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. In which place in the input HTML this comment is located?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post to include more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issue. I removed them using regexes, and for anyone who is curious, here is my new code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import re

input_text = ""

for line in open('output.txt'):
    input_text+=line

#extract all CSS comments
text = re.sub('\/*', '', input_text)
text = re.sub('\*/', '', text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

#extract all HTML comments
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]

print soup
```